# Javascript milliseconds 3 decimal places

Tags: javascript

Currently, my script is working as expected, but I want to show milliseconds in 3 decimal places less than 100

Here is my function:

```
var updateTime = function () {
  var tempTime = elapsedTime;
  var milliseconds = tempTime % 1000;
  tempTime = Math.floor(tempTime / 1000);
  var seconds = tempTime % 60;
  tempTime = Math.floor(tempTime / 60);
  var minutes = tempTime % 60;
  tempTime = Math.floor(tempTime / 60);
  var hours = tempTime % 60;
  
  time = (hours) + ":" + (minutes) + ":" + (seconds) + "." + milliseconds;
  console.log(milliseconds)
  document.getElementById('time').innerText = time
};
```

console.log output:

```
0
0
2
4
5
10
14
17
21
25
30
33
38
41
46
...
81
85
89
93
97
102
105
109
113
117
122
125
```

How can I make the output be like this? =>

```
000
000
002
004
005
010
014
017
021
025
046
...
081
085
089
093
097
102
105
```

I tried using `milliseconds.toFixed(3)` but nothing happened! Could you please help me?

Thank you.

Comment: `String(miliseconds).padStart(3, "0")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
const fmtNum = (num, pad) => String(num).padStart(pad, "0");

time = `${fmtNum(hours, 2)}:${fmtNum(minutes, 2)}:${fmtNum(seconds, 2)}.${fmtNum(milliseconds, 3)}`;
```